# Theres an error trying to show status of OPCache . Laravel and appstract/laravel-opcache

Tags: php, laravel, opcache

Good Day Everyone. This is my first time using opcache in php and because I've use Laravel as my Framework I installed appstract/laravel-opcache package using composer . So here's the error, I tried running the command php artisan opcache:status to get the statistical status of opcache, the stats are showing but theres an error that shows below .

```
General:
+---------------------+-------+
| key                 | value |
+---------------------+-------+
| opcache_enabled     | 1     |
| cache_full          |       |
| restart_pending     |       |
| restart_in_progress |       |
+---------------------+-------+

Memory usage:
+---------------------------+-----------+
| key                       | value     |
+---------------------------+-----------+
| used_memory               | 7.72 MB   |
| free_memory               | 504.28 MB |
| wasted_memory             | 0.00 MB   |
| current_wasted_percentage | 0         |
+---------------------------+-----------+

Interned strings usage:

   ErrorException  : Undefined property: stdClass::$interned_strings_usage

  at E:\XAMPP\htdocs\SWEP\vendor\appstract\laravel-opcache\src\Commands\Status.php:64
    60|         $this->line(PHP_EOL.'Memory usage:');
    61|         $this->table(['key', 'value'], $this->parseTable($data->memory_usage));
    62|
    63|         $this->line(PHP_EOL.'Interned strings usage:');
  > 64|         $this->table(['key', 'value'], $this->parseTable($data->interned_strings_usag
e));
    65|
    66|         $this->line(PHP_EOL.'Statistics:');
    67|         $this->table(['option', 'value'], $this->parseTable($data->opcache_statistics
));
    68|     }

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError("Undefined property: stdC
lass::$interned_strings_usage", "E:\XAMPP\htdocs\SWEP\vendor\appstract\laravel-opcache\src\Co
mmands\Status.php", [Object(stdClass)])
      E:\XAMPP\htdocs\SWEP\vendor\appstract\laravel-opcache\src\Commands\Status.php:64

  2   Appstract\Opcache\Commands\Status::displayTables(Object(stdClass))
      E:\XAMPP\htdocs\SWEP\vendor\appstract\laravel-opcache\src\Commands\Status.php:38
```

Can someone please explain to me why this happened?? This is not a major error because the stats are still showing, I am just worried if someone takes advantage of this error. Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: Report this as an issue to the package maintainer. It's clearly a third party package issue and not related to PHP nor Laravel itself.

Comment: Possible similar issue in a different package https://github.com/amnuts/opcache-gui/issues/26 i'd say that package should catch the failure if `interned_strings_usage` doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks for the Answer sir .. Is interned_strings_usage one of the conf in php.ini ??

Comment: I've checked my php.ini but there is no `interned_strings_usage` but there is `interned_strings_buffer` ..

Answer (score 0):

This is a reported issue in [appstract/laravel-opcache](https://github.com/appstract/laravel-opcache/issues/73)

Update June 23, 2019: this has been fixed by the package maintainer. https://github.com/appstract/laravel-opcache/issues/73#issuecomment-504701864